# Как правильно написать обозначение над кривой на графике - с кавычками или без?

Tags: пунктуация

Мне не нравится авторский вариант, но не могу понять, как правильно написать - здесь имеется в виду, что на графике написано над одной кривой 1 %, а над другими 1 % + TW + WF.
"Об этом свидетельствует график со значком 1%, приведенный на рис. 4.
Поэтому графики для всех переменных модели на этих рисунках обозначены как (1% + TW + WF)".

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он об условностях, предусмотренных для технического текста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Названия следует писать в кавычках. Есть второй вариант: обыграть названия кривых в контексте предложения, что, собственно, и было сделано автором. Хотя и в этой цитате я поставил бы кавычки.

Answer (score 2):

Кавычки нужны, иначе вообще ничего не понять. Это уже написали. Не буду повторять.

Но фраза совсем плохая.

Нормальным языком первое предожение мржно было бы написать так.

**Это видно из графика, обозначенного на рис. XX как "1%".**

Вторая часть моему пониманию просто не поддаётся. Почему "поэтому"? Потому что "свидетельствует"? Поэтому "графики обозначены"?